# God's number for one face of a 3x3x3 Rubik's cube

Tags: group-theory, permutations, rubiks-cube

I'm working on a program to solve a single face on a Rubik's cube. In trying to find a way to reach the optimal number of moves I found God's number (the minimum number of moves needed to solve the cube in any state). My question is what is the God's number for recreating an arbitrary 3x3 pattern of colours on one face of the cube is. To be clear, this means that the cube will have to start off in the solved state and end up in a state where one of the 6 sides perfectly matches a pre-determined 3x3 grid of colours.

I haven't been able to find it anywhere on the web at the moment. I thought to follow the steps used to find God's number for the whole cube to work it out, but I have no idea where to start.

[EDIT]

I wasn't very clear with my question. I've now clarified it.
Thanks to @hamza-abbas-zaidi for help writing.

Comment: When you say a single face, are you referring to a fixed face i.e white? Or can it be selected depending on the permutation of the cube?

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking to solve one colour, my objective is to be able to replicate a pattern on one face of the cube

Comment: When starting from a solved state

Comment: I presume you are make Rubik's Cube Art? So the sides around the face do not matter, nor does the orientation of the face relative to the other centres. I don't think anyone has calculated this before. Maybe you should ask it on the [speedsolving forum, puzzle theory section](https://www.speedsolving.com/forums/puzzle-theory.27/). There's a few people there who might want to try calculating it.

Comment: I suspect this question has the same answer as: what is the max number of moves to go from a scrambled cube to a white face. -- Not based on much but as a white cross (with edges) takes 8 and a full cube 20, I would expect the answer to be closer to the first. Perhaps 10+-2